# sql restriction for join table with string similarity rule

Tags: postgresql

My Db is building from some tables that are similar to each other and share the same column names. The reason is to perform a comparison between data from each resource.

`table_A and table_B: id, product_id, capacitor_name, ressitance`

It is easy to join tables by `product_id` and see the comparison,
but I need to compare data between `product_id` if exists in both tables and if not I want to compare by name similarity and if similarity restricts the result for up to 3 results.

The names most of the time are not equal this is why I'm using a similarity.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a ta 
JOIN table_b tb 
  ON 
    ta.product_id = tb.product_id 
    OR
    similarity(ta.name,tb.name) > 0.8
```

It works fine. But the problem is sometimes I'm getting more data than I need, how can I restrict it? (and moreover, order it by similarity in order to get higher similarity names).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to benefit from an trigram index, you need to use the operator form (%), not the function form.  Then you would order on two "columns", the first to be exact matches first, the 2nd to put most similar matches after and in order.  And use LIMIT to do the limit.  I've assumed you have some WHERE condition to restrict this to just one row of table_a.  If not, then your question is not very well formed.  To what is this limit supposed to apply? Each *what* should be limited to just 3?

```
SELECT * FROM table_a ta 
JOIN table_b tb 
  ON 
    ta.product_id = tb.product_id 
    OR
    ta.name % tb.name
WHERE ta.id=$1
ORDER BY ta.product_id = tb.product_id desc, similarity(ta.name,tb.name) desc
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: thanks , but unfortently, your reasonable assumption is wrong. I need to return array of rows and not only one so 'im not using where in this query and in this way my query is super slow due to nested loop ... i understand why it slow but i want to find way to make it faster.

Comment: But then I don't know what you are asking.  You want at most 3 rows in total?  (And which 3?) At most 3 rows of B for each row of A?  You should figure out what query you want to run before you worry about optimizing it.

Comment: The 3 rows i want are made by product_id comparison if true or the 3 highest similarity comparison.